# How to Stop Watching File Changes

Tags: node.js, babeljs, package.json

I have the following in my package.json file

```
  "scripts": {
    "babel": "babel es6.js --watch --out-file es6-compiled.js"
  },
```

and I can watch files via

```
$ npm run babel
```

What I haven't figured out yet is how to STOP watching files.

So I've been running CTL-C to break out of watch, but that cant be right.

Is there any official way to stop watching files?

thanks

Comment: Why do you think is not right? If you mean transpiling the files without watching them just remove the `--watch` parameter

Comment: @SunriseM re:"Why?" Not sure, New to node and babel, so I wasn't sure CTL-C was the "right" way to do it. re: "just remove the --watch parameter" - that works too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
   "babel": "babel es6.js --watch --out-file es6-compiled.js"
```

Try

```
   "babel": "babel es6.js --out-file es6-compiled.js"
```

It should do the trick.